# How to Import a class from a different folder in python?

Tags: python, import, module, directory

```
     common/src/validation/file1.py
```

In the common/src/validation folder "*_init_*" is defined.

```
     common/test/validation/file2.py
     common/test/validation/case/file3.py
```

In file2.py and file3.py, I want to import class from file1.py.

Im giving the following line in file2.py and file3.py.:

```
      from file1 import class1
```

I currently get error:

```
      #ImportError: No module named file1
```

what should be the sys.path.append ?

Comment: `__init__` or `__init__.py`?

Comment: What's the exact code and error?

Comment: yes it is *__init__*.py.

Comment: in file2 and file3, i am trying to give - from file1 import class1. error is # ImportError: No module named file1.   Not sure how exactly this is done...!

Answer (score 7):

You should add the module to your python PATH in the beginning of your script. So in the beginning of your file2.py and file3.py, you should have the following:

```
sys.path.append('/src/validation/')
from file1 import class1
```

And don't forget to create the __init__.py in your /src/validation/ directory.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just changed the folder structure. could you tell me what should the sys.path.append look like?

Comment: @abcde sys.path represents the python path. I.e. the path to the python modules. Python looks into this variable to find any command it finds (in addition to system environment variables). So if you want to import a class from a module which is not already in your python path, it should be appended to your sys.path using sys.path.append. Before that, of course, you need to import sys.

Comment: @ shahram thank you for the explanation. for the above directory structure in the question, could you pls tell me what should be the path to sys.path.append ? I am new to this work and not able to provide the right path... thanks

Comment: @abcde: If 'common' is in your root directory, you should have these lines in the beginning of file2.py and file3.py: `import sys 
   sys.path.append('/common/src/validation/')
   from file1 import class1`