# How do I import from another folder in python?

Tags: python, python-import

I've seen tips on [how to import from a subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/import-a-module-from-a-relative-path). The problem is importing from another folder in the same parent folder. The current structure is like this:

```
test 
__init__.py
|-- folder1
|-- __init__.py
| |-- A.py
|-- folder2
| |-- __init__.py
| |-- B.py
```

A.py is:

```
hi = 1 
print "hi", hi
```

B.py is:

```
from folder1 import A

print "imported"
```

When I do `python B.py`, I get an error:

```
  File "B.py", line 1, in <module>
    from folder1 import A
ImportError: No module named folder1
```

How can I import A.py? Ideally, folder structure does not change.

Comment: What python version?

Comment: what is the python path?

Comment: python version 2.7, I'm using anaconda python in my home directory, /Applications/anaconda/bin/python

Comment: Does this help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/python-relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33773202/how-to-import-a-class-from-a-different-folder-in-python/33773635

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `folder1` and `folder2` are subpackages, and the package is the parent directory i.e. `test`.

Whatever path the parent directory of `test` is will need to be in your `sys.path`.  You can do this, for example, with the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

Then you should have, in module `B.py`:

```
from test.folder1 import A
```