# Python can't find my module

Tags: python, path, package

I have a python project (which I run within a virtualenv) and that has the following structure:

```
Project
├───.git
├───venv
└───src
    ├───__init__.py
    ├───mymodules
    │   ├───__init__.py
    │   ├───module1.py
    │   └───module2.py
    └───scripts
        ├───__init__.py
        └───script.py
```

script.py

```
import src.mymodules.module1
...
```

---

I run the project with venv activated and from the Project directory using the following command:

```
(venv)$ python src/scripts/script.py
```

The script runs but gives out the following error before exiting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/scripts/script.py", line 1, in <module>
    import src.mymodules.module1
ImportError: No module named src.mymodules.module1
```

I have tried running the python shell and trying to import the module from there and it gave no errors. I have _ _init__.py in every directory within src. Is python considering the working directory to be src/scripts? Why is that happening and how can I make src the working directory if that's the case?

Comment: Python 2 or 3? 3 has a different way of handling package module imports.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33773202/how-to-import-a-class-from-a-different-folder-in-python/33773635#33773635

Comment: I've tried `sys.path.append('/src')` and `sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))))` still to no avail.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Essentially, when you execute `script.py` directly, it doesn't know that it's part of a submodule of `src`, nor does it know where a module named `src` might be. This is the case in either python 2 or 3.

As you know, Python finds modules based on the contents of [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path). In order to import any module, it must either be located in a directory that's listed in `sys.path`, or, in the same directory as the script that you're running.

When you say `python src/scripts/script.py`, `sys.path` includes the `Project/src/scripts/` (because that's where `script.py` is located), but not `Project`. Because `Project` isn't in the path, the modules in that directory (`src`) aren't able to be imported.

To fix this:

I'm assuming that your `script.py` is an entry point for your `src` module (for example, maybe it's the main program). If that's true, then you could fix it by moving `script.py` up to the same level as `src`:

```
Project
├───.git
├───venv
|───script.py       <--- script.py moves up here
└───src
    ├───__init__.py
    └───mymodules
        ├───__init__.py
        ├───module1.py
        └───module2.py
```

This way, `script.py` can freely import anything in `src`, but nothing in `src` can import `script.py`.

If that's not the case, and `script.py` really is a part of `src`, you can use python's [`-m`](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m) argument to execute `script.py` as part of the `src` module like so:

```
$ python -m src.scripts.script
```

Because you've told python which module you're running (`src`), it will be in the path. So, `script.py` will be aware that it's a submodule of `src`, and then will be able to import from `src`.

Be careful in this situation though - there's potential to create a circular import if something in `src` imports `src.scripts.script`.

---

As an alternative to both of these approaches, you can modify the `sys.path` directly in `script.py`:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/Project') # location of src
```

While this works, it's not usually my preference. It requires `script.py` to know exactly how your code is laid out, and may cause import confusion if another python program ever tries to import `script.py`.

Comment: Thanks, all 3 options work. The first one isn't an option for this project. The third one is not very elegant for the reason you stated. For now, I think I'll be using `python -m src.scripts.script`. I thought it would be enough to structure it like a package, as I've seen stated in other questions here?

Comment: Python doesn't go "up" directory levels to find packages for various reasons. And submodules can and do import siblings, but mostly packages are intended to be used by other programs (and installed into a system package directory), not necessarily to be programs in themselves. This part of python can be confounding, but it does make some sense.

Comment: `python -m src.scripts.script` approach really helped me out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: the most clear and straight answer I've see for the `python import` myth, instead of explicitly adding `sys.path.insert...` to source code, could use `PYTHONPATH=/path/to/Project python script.py` to get same goal.

Comment: @Shawn, good point. Setting the PYTHONPATH environment variable removes the script's need to know where it's located on disk (which will cause it to break if anything in the path is renamed).

Answer (score 6):

```
Project
├───.git
├───venv
└───src
    ├───__init__.py
    ├───mymodules
    │   ├───__init__.py
    │   ├───module1.py
    │   └───module2.py
    └───scripts
        ├───__init__.py
        └───script.py
```

Alternatively you can import like the following in your script.py

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'../../'))
import src.mymodules.module1
```

Now you can run script.py file from any location.

```
e.g :
python script.py
python /path to folder/script.py
```

Comment: Your solution makes total sense, but doesn't seem to be working for me. Any thoughts? A RegressionTest folder contains an entrypoint file, say 'test.py' and another moduel 'check_results.py'. I want to import a utilities module from ../utils/CrossPlatform, so I do sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))) in the test.py, which then imports check_results.py. In check_results, sys.path yields the top level package that I'd expect. But, check_results cannot find utils (from utils.CrossPlatform import myutil.py). All folders have __init__,py. Thanks.

Comment: Nuts. The issue was a conflicting module name somewhere in anaconda install path which is also called scripts and has __init__.py.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is creating file `some_file.pth` and write your project dir (mother dir of your src). Put this file in `/virtual_env/lib/pythonXX/site-packages/`. In this way, you don't need to import `sys.path` in your script.

Comment: Thank you! this worked great. Do you happen to know what this does under the hood?

Answer (score 2):

If you face this problem when dealing with `Pytest` or `coverage`. Adding `__init__.py` file solve most of the cases.