# Python - ImportError: No module Cloud Dataproc

Tags: python, import, google-cloud-dataproc

I am having an issue with Google Cloud Dataproc with the structuring of my python project. I have a number of files which are all in the same folders and which call one another through `import`. The overall program runs fine locally.

However, when I place it in Google Cloud Dataproc, I have an issue with `import`. I have tried the answers presented in this [Python can't find my module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33862963/python-cant-find-my-module) answer but to no effect.

The error is the following:

```
from model import PolicyEmergence
ImportError: No module named model
```

I tried to force the path using `sys.path.insert(0, 'gs://bucket-name/')` but to no avail. I am not sure if this is due to the changing path every time I run the job.

Any help would be welcome, thanks.

Comment: As Toorusr mentions you can't import files from GCS -- only ones on the local filesystem. `pyspark` (and `gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark`) let you specify `--py-files` that should be available for import. Here is the documentation https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html. What's the command you are using to submit your job?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This helped me pinpoint the problem. I am using the console directly and thought that only importing the main file would lead GCS locate all other files in the same folder. When I specify each of the files separately, the problem is resolved. Thanks for the link, I'll use that for bundling as I have too many files to import each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The `from [...] import [...]` requires as first argument a [directory.]file
>   where your classes are and secondly a specific name of your class or * you want to import from there.
>
> for example:

```
     # The .py must be omitted! 
     from mymodule import *
```

To import your class (PolicyEmergence) from that file (model.py) you should delete the [.py]:

```
from model import PolicyEmergence
```

Tusr

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As mentioned before, the .py was added in one of my tests, removing it does not change anything. As for using: from my module import *, the same error occurs: from model import *
ImportError: No module named model

Comment: I think if you want to import the folders directly form cloud, it is not possible, may be you can first get them and then place them in your foulder?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want:

```
from model import PolicyEmergence
```

Comment: also OP make sure that the said file is withing the same directory that you are importing it from

Comment: yes, sorry the from model.py was a test I was doing. I corrected my question. As for the files, they are all in the same folder (bucket) on Google cloud.