# Python3 Module import from different files

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have a project in python that uses a file structure similar to this:

```
program/
    main.py
    SubFolder/
        module1.py
        module2.py
    TestFolder/
        test.py
```

In this structure `main.py` imports `module2.py` and `module2.py` imports `module1.py`. Also `test.py` imports `module2.py`.

I have two problems with the imports in this folder structure.

When running the `main.py` the import in `module2.py` is as follows:

```
from SubFolder.module1 import *
```

Here the the folder of `main.py` is set as the root folder and all the imports are done from there. While when I run `module2.py` directly the import should be as follows:

```
from module1 import *
```

Because now the root folder is the folder of `module2.py`. This is a problem, because now the import statements constantly need to be changed when running from different files. Is there any solution to this?

The second problem is when I want to run `test.py`, this file imports `module2.py`. The way to import this should be:

```
from ..SubFolder.module2 import *
```

But this gives the following error message:

```
    from ..SubFolder.module2 import *
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I have looked at a lot of solutions for this, but could not find one that worked. Is there any way to fix this.

Is there someone that could explain to me how I could resolve these issues?

I have already looked at this: [Relative imports in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3), but this does not resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a `__init__` file

```
program/
    main.py
    SubFolder/
        __init__.py
        module1.py
        module2.py
    TestFolder/
        test.py
```

in `__init__.py`, import all the files in same directory

```
from SubFolder.module1 import *
from SubFolder.module2 import *
```

in `main.py`, import Subfolder

```
from Subfolder import *
function_inside_module1()
```

Now you can access any object in module1 and module 2.
`__init__.py` works just like `def __init__` in a class function,
It will execute itself once the parent directory (module) is imported.
so in `main.py`, it will be executed as:

```
from SubFolder.module1 import *
from SubFolder.module2 import *
function_inside_module1()
```

**Note**: with `import Subfolder` you will need to call functions like this:

```
import Subfolder
Subfolder.function_inside_module1()
```

we now look at the module 2 import problem, this is already solved when `__init__.py` is created. because now python sees it as a module and can be imported anywhere.
in module2,

```
from SubFolder.module1 import *
```

will now work at any working directory

same for `test.py`,

```
from SubFolder.module2 import *
```

will also work in `test.py`

**Warning**: Do not do this in module files and expect normal results

```
#  in module1:
from SubFolder.module1 import *
#  AND in module2:
from SubFolder.module2 import *
```

this will cause circular import and result in import error or names being undefined

Comment: damn, this took more time than I thought, experimented with modules, interesting ques

Comment: Thanks for the explenation, the `__init__` file seems to work for the `main.py`. Only `module1.py` and `test.py` now both give the error: 
`from SubFolder.module1 import *    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SubFolder'`
Is this because of my IDE? I am using Visual Studio Code.

Comment: @LRV2K1 I am not very sure if it's your IDE, I am using pycharm and it worked but it may be other factors. maybe you will want to see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33862963/python-cant-find-my-module)

Comment: Thanks for the awnsers, I checked in pycharm and it does work there. Therefore I will for now be switching to pycharm for this project.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you just create empty `__init__.py` files in subFolder and then import  it as following:  `from subFolder.module1 import *`.